# Is associativity of operators documented?

Tags: operators

[Operator precedence is documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations.html). [Operators without built-in meanings are documented](http://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#41).
The word "associative" apparently does not appear in either page. It's easy enough to do an experiment to observe the associativity of an operator. For example, `\[CircleMinus]` is left-associative and `\[CirclePlus]` is not:

```
ClearAll[CirclePlus, CircleMinus];
CircleMinus[a_, b_] := a[b];
CirclePlus[a_, b_] := a[b];

a⊖b⊖c
a⊕b⊕c
(a⊕b)⊕c
```

> ```
> a[b][c]
> a⊕b⊕c
> a[b][c]
> ```

But it would be nicer to discover associativity without an experiment. Neither operator has `Attributes`, let alone attributes that reveal associativity.

```
In[534]:= ClearAll[CirclePlus, CircleMinus];
Attributes[CircleMinus]
Attributes[CirclePlus]
```

> ```
> {}
> {}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some relevant documentation here:

```
http://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html
```

[image]

What we see is that a difference between CirclePlus and CircleMinus is that CirclePlus takes multiple inputs while CircleMinus takes only two. For example:

CirclePlus[f1, f2, f3, f4]

evaluates nicely while

```
CircleMinus[f1, f2, f3]
```

does not (the third argument is red and the command is ignored). So I suspect that what you are perceiving as associativity is a result of the difference in the allowable inputs to the two expressions.